# Loading NPAPI plugin in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I have a NPAPI API based (scriptable) plugin developed using Gecko SDK 1.9.2. This plugin works fine on FF3.6 & FF4 beta, but it fails to get detected on chrome.

Also I cannot see the plugin listed - when I do a *"about:Plugins"* in chrome.
I've registered the plugin as described in the "[Windows Installation Using the Registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview#MS_Windows)".

When monitored the chrome startup using Sysinternals tool Procmon.exe, I could find that the chrome tries to do a LoadImage on my Plugin dll, whoever it quickly unloads it.

Any ideas why this plugin is not detected by chrome will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the plugin dll didn't have the resource like file description, MIME type and language set. Adding the proper resource strings fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to have an example of exactly what keys you used and where you put them; [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) plugins (works on all npapi and activex browsers) register themselves in the registry using that method and they work fine on chrome.

Depending on your needs, might even be worth looking into building your plugin in FireBreath instead of using npapi directly -- it's a lot less work and workarounds for various browsers have already been done.

One thing to try is to make sure you have the file name correct in the registry; Many versions of firefox just use the directory specified in the registry and search for any plugin files (this isn't documented, AFAIK, it's just my observations), whereas Chrome actually uses the path and file.  It's also possible you could have a permissions issue.

Comment: Thanks Taxilian, but where do I get a sample plugin developed using FireBreath? When I downloaded the SDK it had an example, but wouldn't compile with VS 2010. I just want something real quick to check what registry entries are absolutely required for Chrome.

Comment: When you download FireBreath it comes with two examples. You need cmake to build it, but it will build with Visual Studio 2005 or later -- I use VS 2010 to build it every day and it works fine.  see http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Building+on+Windows